# push Main page to second page

Tags: flutter

I have five items on the main screen, and what I want to do when one is pressed it goes to the corresponding page.  Not sure exactly how to use the InkWell function to be able to push the tap from the first main page to the second page.  .

Not sure if I am on the right track with the code below or need to go into another direction.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './food_catefgories.dart';
import './main_categories_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Made in Canada Stuff',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        canvasColor: Color.fromRGBO(225, 254, 229, 1),
        textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
             body1: TextStyle(
               color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
             ),
             body2: TextStyle(
               color: Color.fromRGBO(20, 51, 51, 1),
             ),
             title: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 20,
               fontFamily: 'RobotoCondensed',
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
             )),
      ),
      home: MainCategoriesScreen(),
      initialRoute: '/spalsh',
         routes: {
            '/splash': (context) => MainCategoriesScreen(),
            '/one': (context) => OneCategoriesScreen(),
            '/two': (context) => TwoCategoriesScreen(),
            '/three': (context) => ThreeCategoriesScreen(),
            '/four': (context) => FourCategoriesScreen(),
            '/five': (context) => FiveCategoriesScreen(),
  },
    );
  }
}
```

main_categories_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './category_item.dart';

class Category {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final Color color;

  const Category({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.color = Colors.orange,
  });
}

const MAINCAT_CATEGORIES = const [
  Category(
    id: 'c1',
    title: "ONE",
    color: Colors.purple,
  ),
  Category(
    id: 'c2',
    title: "TWO",
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
Category(
    id: 'c3',
    title: "THREE",
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
];

class MainCategoriesScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Made title'),
      ),
      body: GridView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25),
      children: MAINCAT_CATEGORIES
          .map((catData) => CategoryItem(
            catData.title,
            catData.color,
          ),

          )
          .toList(),
      gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
        maxCrossAxisExtent: 200,
        childAspectRatio: 3 / 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 20,
        mainAxisSpacing: 20,
      ),
    ),
    ); 
  }
}
```

category_item.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './main_categories_screen.dart';

class CategoryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;
  final Color color;

  CategoryItem(this.title, this.color);

  void selectCategory(BuildContext ctx) {
    Navigator.of(ctx).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) {
      return MainCategoriesScreen();
    },),);
  }

  @override 
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
        onTap: () => selectCategory(context),
        splashColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15), 
        child: Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
      child: Text(title,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.title,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: LinearGradient(
        colors: [
          color.withOpacity(0.7),
          color,
      ],
      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
      end: Alignment.bottomRight,
      ),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Look at flutter documentation. There's a sample in the cookbook https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate from one screen to another and pass the data using Navigate class 
For Example i'm using in my app.

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
 (context) => Home(userRole: role)),
 ModalRoute.withName('/home'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: 
 (context) => Home(userRole: role))),
```

or

```
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/first');
```

Make sure before using second line you have to declared all page in your MaterialApp like

```
initialRoute: '/spalsh',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => LoginScreen(),
    '/spalsh':(context)=>SplashScreen(),
    '/first': (context) => FirstScreen(),
    '/leave': (context) => ApplyLeave(),
    '/bill': (context) => ApplyBill(),
    '/contact': (context) => ContactUs(),
    '/four': (context) => ScreenFour(),
    '/five': (context) => ScreenFive(),
    '/six': (context) => ScreenSix(),
    '/seven': (context) => ScreenSeven(),
  },
```

Comment: Sorry new to Flutter,  exactly how does Navigator.push know which item when tapped?  Also I added my main.dart to the above code

Answer (score 0):

```
//Navigate to other page with class name and parameters
 Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FoodCategoriesScreen(title:"Items")));
//class name is FoodCategoriesScreen and the parameter is title to which we are assigning a value "Items".
//Navigator through routes that you have specified in your code (without parameters)
 Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/food');
```

Comment: Sorry, I have edited my question as I think is was confusing.  I have 5 items on the main page that when pressed I need to go to the corresponding page.